# Вложенный цикл с условием

Tags: python, циклы

Есть такой код:

```
s = []
for z in range(4): 
    for k in range(14):
        if (E[z] / ((S[k]+0.1) * D[z])) <= D[k]:
            s.append(S[k])
```

Создаю пустой список и в него вписываю значение если выполняется условие. Но если условие выполнено, то цикл все равно идет дальше и вписывает еще значения в список. 
Вопрос : как за один "прогон" по `k` в список вписывать только 1 значение, то , для которого первым выполнится исходное условие.

Comment: просто `break` написать не если условие выполнилось?

Comment: в конце самом, после аппенда?

Comment: ну да а как иначе то

Comment: спасибо, подошло, а еще вопрос: в данном примере было range(4), а если это будет просто считываться столбец, с n-значениям, можно как-то прописать, чтобы range был длиной со столбец?

Comment: ну как вариант `len(n)`

Comment: да, так и сделал, и почему то цикл перестал работать, выдает : KeyError: 11, причем даже если поставить range(100) уже ошибка, хотя len = 14000 где-то

Comment: покажите полный код, потому что не особо понятно что да как у вас

Comment: `x= pd.read_excel('res11.xlsx')

a = len(x.E)

s = []

for z in range(a):
 ` и дальше часть уже была

Comment: у вас `a` выводит число?

Comment: да ,конечно. Просто range ограничен вообще 10 только значениями, range(11) проходит, range(12) уже крах

Comment: @Max52, по-моему, в данном случае было бы полезнее показать исходные DataFrame'ы и выходной DataFrame и спросить о векторизированном Pandas-решении...